# Bootstrap background images grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I'm starting with bootstrap, learning tutorials, etc. I want to build a page with only images (many) forming a background, with no borders and space between them. Kind of mosaic.

Have tried many things, including some tutorial bootstrap grid system but I didnt found a clue.

I've found some jQuery stuff, but using bootstrap would be a plus. Could it be responsive?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"> 
      <img src="http://www.streetartutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Street-Art-by-David-Walker-in-London-England.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it can be responsive.

To get rid of spaces between the images
If you use Bootstrap 3, it's much easier. Bootstrap 3 now used padding instead of margins to create the "gutter" in your css.

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Then just add no-gutter to any rows where spacing is to be removed exmple:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-lg-6"> 
    <img src="http://www.streetartutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Street-Art-by-David-Walker-in-London-England.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"> 
    <img src="http://www.streetartutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Street-Art-by-David-Walker-in-London-England.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

To get all images at equal height

```
img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

for image height 100% regardless of width in order not to stretch the image

```
img {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

okies so my fault I used '.img' and not 'img' above

now you can use pull-left class as

```
<div class="col-lg-6 pull-left"> 
    <img src="http://www.streetartutopia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Street-Art-by-David-Walker-in-London-England.jpg"  alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

OR

```
img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3v2zg/734/)

Comment: Yes :) one question more. I have what I expected, but some images have diferent heights. Bootstrap css sets height: auto for images. It wont be a problem, but that diferent heights is causing white spaces between images. You know the tricky? It woulde be nice if images stick to which other even if they have diferent sizes :)

Comment: do you want all images of equal heights?

Comment: I can "play" with columns, since that bootstrap expects 12 cols. But some images have diferent heights which makes appear blank spaces to till that diferences. Ill try to show it. http://s30.postimg.org/tujkhnkmp/imgs.png. It would be nice if that images could fit each other. Does bootstrap allows it?

Comment: Or, yes all images of equal heights would be more simple. If i'm asking to much with coment before :)

Comment: Ok, thank you once again :) Now i need to figure it out a way to dont stretch the images. Even if it wont show the entire image. This way, the images are being resized

Comment: Images just got bigger :D I've done something playing with background images and positions. It seems nice but it ruins the responsive thing.

Comment: give img height equal to your div height in px.

Comment: AS IS: http://s18.postimg.org/c9gytllhl/as_is.png TO BE: http://s10.postimg.org/p3ueo3y1l/to_be.png (or centered)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, this should give a line of 6 images tight together. 
Could be for two images "col-md-6" or three with "col-md-4". 
Its important to make css for "#image-div .col-md-2" or "#image-div .row" so as to not effect these classes in other grids in the page only within #image-div or whatever you call it.

> CSS PART

```
<style>
    #image-div .row{
      margin-top:0px ;
      margin-bottom:0px ;
      margin-left:0px ;
      margin-right:0px ;
      padding-top:0px ;
      padding-bottom:0px ;
      padding-left:0px ;
      padding-right:0px ;
    }
    #image-div .col-md-2{
      margin-top:0px ;
      margin-bottom:0px ;
      margin-left:0px ;
      margin-right:0px ;
      padding-top:0px ;
      padding-bottom:0px ;
      padding-left:0px ;
      padding-right:0px ;
    }

  </style>
```

---

> HTML PART

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">image.jpg</div>
   </div>
```